# 2 filters with query not working in elasticSearch, java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This is my old code which is working fine

```
qb = QueryBuilders.queryString(query.replaceAll(" ", " OR ").replaceAll(",", " AND ").replaceAll("!", " NOT "));
FilterBuilder fb = FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("Experiance").from(smonth).to(emonth));
 FilteredQueryBuilder fqBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(qb, fb);

org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits =  node.client()
                .prepareSearch(name)                
                .setQuery(fqBuilder)
```

In this piece of code, I am searching those data whose experience between smonth and emonth.

Now i need to add more filters in my search, So i move to 'NativeSearchQueryBuilder'. After modification, I write this code:-

```
qb = QueryBuilders.queryString(query.replaceAll(" ", " OR ").replaceAll(",", " AND ").replaceAll("!", " NOT "));
FilterBuilder fb = FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("Experiance").from(smonth).to(emonth));
NativeSearchQueryBuilder builder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
        builder.withQuery(qb);
        AndFilterBuilder filters = null;
        filters = new AndFilterBuilder(fb);
       filters.add(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("providedZipcode", zipcode))));  //third filter
        builder.withFilter(filters);


org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits =  node.client()
                .prepareSearch(name)                
                .setQuery(builder.build().getQuery());
```

But when i am searching then filter is not working. I am not getting data according to experience and zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

We can use setPostFilter

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits =  node.client()
                .prepareSearch(name)
              //  .setIndices(name)
                 .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setQuery(fqBuilder)
                .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("providedZipcode", zipcode))));  // Filter
```

But i have another problem. If i didnt pass zipcode then it's not showing data. I want to get all data if i not pass any zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

You look like you would actually benefit more from using a bool filter, with two  condiditons in addition to the query string. We will be searching all documents that hopefully match the `providedZipcode` but definitely have experience ranging from `smonth` to `emonth`. In my answer, I used a `bool` filter to implement this logic.

Post Filter in your above answer isn't really the functionality that you are looking for. It executes your request using the original query, and then filters the results of that original query by the second filter.

This is how I wrote up your request:

```java
QueryStringQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryString(query
                                                .replaceAll(" ", " OR ")
                                                .replaceAll(",", " AND ")
                                                .replaceAll("!", " NOT "));

FilterBuilder fb = FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
            .should(FilterBuilders.termFilter("providedZipcode", zipcode))
            .must(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("Experiance").from(smonth).to(emonth));


FilteredQueryBuilder fqb = new FilteredQueryBuilder(qb, fb);
```

Comment: Sorry, But i tried your code. I am not passing zipcode, After that it's giving this error org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException      Here is complete exception http://pastebin.com/cwr1mXnJ

Comment: I modified your code. Can i use this?  BoolFilterBuilder btu= FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
   FilterBuilder fb = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
   if(zipcode!=null){
    btu=btu.must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("providedZipcode", zipcode));
   }
   if(smonth!=null && emonth!=null){
    btu=btu.must(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("Experiance").from(smonth).to(emonth));
   }
   fb=btu;
     FilteredQueryBuilder fqBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(qb, fb);

Comment: here it's also showing those records which doesnt have query string. any idea why?

Comment: Yes, the code is a good start. You forgot to use `btu` in a `FilteredQueryBuilder` with the `QueryStringBuilder` `qb` that you see in my request